# Missing JAR resource containing TLD

Tags: jsp, tags, tld, custom-tag

**I have create a library** -- **customtags.jar**

[image]

**taglib.tld structure is as follow**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">

<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<short-name>custom</short-name>
<uri>taglib</uri>

<tag-file> 
    <name>label</name> 
    <path>/WEB-INF/tags/Label.tag</path> 
</tag-file> 
<tag-file> 
    <name>textarea</name> 
    <path>/WEB-INF/tags/TextArea.tag</path> 
</tag-file> 
<tag-file> 
    <name>textfield</name> 
    <path>/WEB-INF/tags/TextField.tag</path> 
</tag-file>
```

**In index.jsp Page**

```
<%@taglib prefix="custom" uri="customtags.jar"%>
```

[image]

**if I change**

```
<%@taglib prefix="custom" uri="WEB-INF/lib/customtags.jar"%>
```

[image: enter code here]

Please correct and update me !

Comment: Did you add the jar file to your classpath?

Comment: Yes you did or yes that solved the issue?

Comment: jar file already added in classpath. @KevinBowersox

Comment: Problem still there @KevinBowersox , please find the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `tags` directory directly under `WEB-INF` and placing your `jar` in this directory.

Notice that this error mentions it is looking in this directory:
[image]

Comment: How to resolve this ? but the first error is different from this ? have u any resolution with respect to first error :)

Comment: how to combine my tag files into jar and use them in jsp :)